# How to cut string from pattern until pattern using sed/awk in bash

Tags: awk, sed

I can not figure out, how to use sed or awk to trim string in file. I've been searching many hours without desired result.
I have a string like this:

```
c=one, o=roll, root ca          valid until: date
c=one, o=roll, root ca          Located: location
c=two roll, root ca             valid until: date
c=two roll, root ca             Located: location
```

My desired output align in columns:

```
c=one            valid until: date
c=one            Located: location
c=two roll       valid until: date
c=two roll       Located: location
```

I'm using sed command which does not work like (and many others):

```
sed 's/,.*\^([valid])//g' file.txt
```

but I can't figure out second condition until word "valid", in addition "valid" and "Location" at the same command.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `sed` doesn't have advanced regex features like lookaround and lookaheads - matching "up until" can be only done in a greedy way.

Comment: Look at what you have written. Can you see a subtle error in your logic? Perhaps you are looking for [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ sed -E 's/,.*(valid|Located)/ \1/' ip.txt
c=one valid until: date
c=one Located: location
```

You could put the terms `valid`, `Located` (and any other such terms you want) inside a capture group of alternations. Then use backreference `\1` in replacement section to put it back.

To align the output, you could use some character like `|` which doesn't occur in input and then use `column` command

```
$ sed -E 's/,.*(valid|Located)/|\1/' ip.txt | column -t -s'|'
c=one       valid until: date
c=one       Located: location
c=two roll  valid until: date
c=two roll  Located: location
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great, but this break up the alignment in columns, is there a way to keep it?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, tested and written with shown samples.

```
awk -F'[, ]' 'match($0,/ +valid.*| +Located.*/){print $1,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks, there is output:
`c=one       valid until: date
c=one       Located: location
c=two roll       valid until: date
c=two roll       Located: location`

Comment: @GeoFery, I believe its keeping the space also preserved which are coming before valid or Located too.

Comment: sadly no, it can be done by another formating in the long script however i made a mistake, coz your command left everything at the beginning of the line since first space, not until comma comes, however many thanks for effort

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to rely on `valid` or `Located`, with the command below, there can be any word there:

```
sed 's/,.*[^ ]\(   *[^ ][^:]*:\)/\1/'  file
```

Or, you may force to match up to `valid` or `Located` using

```
sed -E 's/,.*[^[:space:]]([[:space:]]{2,}(valid|Located))/\1/' file
sed -E 's/,.*\S(\s{2,}(valid|Located))/\1/' file     # If \s and \S are supported
```

where `(valid|Located)` matches either a `valid` or `Located` character sequences. Note that for the OR `|` operator to work, you need to either escape it in a POSIX BRE pattern, or enable the POSIX ERE syntax with the `-E` option, as shown above.

See the [online `sed` demo #1](https://ideone.com/koellN) and a [demo #2](https://ideone.com/zPt3Ld). **Details**

- `,` - match the first comma
- `.*` - match any 0 or more chars
- `[^ ]` - then find a non-space char
- `\(   *[^ ][^:]*:\)` - captures into Group 1 (`\1`) 2 or more spaces followed with a non-space char (`[^ ]`) and then 0 or more chars other than `:` (`[^:]*`) and then a `:`.

You may replace space with `\s` (if supported) or `[[:space:]]` to match any whitespace, and `[^ ]` with `[^[:space:]]` or `\S` (if supported).

Comment: @GeoFery I am glad it worked, but I see you have some doubts. Do you need to adjust it for something else?

Comment: Nope, that was fine, just wanted to keep columns which Sundeep updated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove everything up until multiple consecutive spaces, assuming there are no double spaces in the left column:

```
s/,.*     /     /
```